# how to use tortoiseHg with Mercurial to download the google open source code?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I want to download http://code.google.com/p/android-traditional-chinese-ime/source/checkout this.
But how to use tortoiseHg2.7 with Mercurial to download the google open source code?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that project is using a Subversion repository, so if you want to get the source as a Mercurial repo, you have a couple of choices, both of which use Mercurial extensions.

One is [HgSubversion](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion), which will allow you to work directly with the Subversion repository, in theory allowing you to push changes back to the project.  It doesn't come with Mercurial (or TortoiseHg) so you'd have to download it separately.  I've not used it so can't really comment on it.

The other option is [Convert](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) which *does* come with Mercurial - you just need to enable it, which in TortoiseHg you can do by selecting user-config and checking the "Convert" box in the Extensions section.  Again, I've not used it to work with a Subversion repo, so can't do much more than point you at the extension page, which has some useful information.

Alternatively you could use Subversion itself, which is more likely to work with the repository without issue.  I'd recommend getting [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) - it should do just what you want.

Comment: I have downloaded  TortoiseSVN but how to use it?

Comment: Well, you could always have a look [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-quick-start.html).